Weird spacing using inline hebrew with XeLaTex and polyglossia
I'm currently writing my master's thesis in old testament studies and am struggling with typesetting inline hebrew.
I use XeLaTeX and polyglossia with the following configuration:
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{german}
\setotherlanguages{hebrew, greek}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Ezra SIL}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek]{GFS Artemisia}

\newcommand{\texthb}[1]{\beginR\begin{hebrew}#1\endR\end{hebrew}}
\newcommand{\textgr}[1]{\begin{greek}#1\end{greek}}

Here's an example of me using my macro command:
Innerhalb des Textes finden sich mehrere prominente semantische Felder. Zunächst fallen beim Lesen verschiedene Begriffes des Feldes "`Hören/Geräusche"' auf. Dazu gehören \texthb{שׁמעה} ("`höre"', 2a), \texthb{ושׁועתי} ("`mein Ruf"', 2b), \texthb{אזנך} ("`dein Ohr"', 3a), \texthb{אקרא} ("`ich rufe"', 3b), \texthb{מקול אנחתי} ("`vom Geräusch meines Seufzens"', 6a) und \texthb{לשׁמע אנקת} ("`um das Stöhnen zu hören"', 21a).

And here's the output:

As you can see, there is way too much space to the right of my hebrew terms. How can I fix this?
Thanks for your help!
Edit: Here's a complete document that replicates the issue:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{german}
\setotherlanguages{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Ezra SIL}

\newcommand{\texthb}[1]{\beginR\begin{hebrew}#1\endR\end{hebrew}}

\begin{document}

Innerhalb des Textes finden sich mehrere prominente semantische Felder. Zunächst fallen beim Lesen verschiedene Begriffes des Feldes "`Hören/Geräusche"' auf. Dazu gehören \texthb{שׁמעה} ("`höre"', 2a), \texthb{ושׁועתי} ("`mein Ruf"', 2b), \texthb{אזנך} ("`dein Ohr"', 3a), \texthb{אקרא} ("`ich rufe"', 3b), \texthb{מקול אנחתי} ("`vom Geräusch meines Seufzens"', 6a) und \texthb{לשׁמע אנקת} ("`um das Stöhnen zu hören"', 21a).

\end{document}


please provide a small test document that makes the output shown, don't make us guess what is needed to make a test document from the provided fragments

there was a bug in an older version https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/459 leading to additional spaces. So check your package version.

@DavidCarlisle I've added an example document that replicates the issue.

@UlrikeFischer overleaf uses texlive 2023 which should use a relatively recent version of polyglossia without this bug, right?

I get this output in texlive 2024

you should also increase baselineskip (or scale the Hebrew down a bit) as the specified baseline spacing is lost on all lines that have Hebrew

@NiklasSchulze If you ask the overleaf support, they can switch your project to texlive 2024.

@DavidCarlisle thanks, I've setup a local xelatex environment with texlive 24 and it works!

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thanks, I'll ask them!
